# how can I extract the content of a tag in c#, like <Name> Jhon Doe </Name> output: {"Name": "Jhon Doe"}

Tags: c#

From my backend I am consuming a web service that returns the following:

```
<!-- this is the info of the user --> \r\n<User>\r\n<Name>Jhon Doe</Name>\r\n<Identification>10538181</Identification>\r\n<Email>JhonDoe@gmail.com</Email></User>
```

I want to extract the text contained in these tags: `<Name>` `<Identification>` `<Email>` since I am new to `c#` I want to know which is the best way to achieve it

This is my desired output:

output:

```
{
"Name":"Jhon Doe",
"Identification":10538181,
"Email":"JhonDoe@gmail.com",
}
```

how can do it?

Comment: You parse XML (it looks like one) to a class and then serialize this class to json.

Comment: Sometimes you can request the data in xml or json format. Check to see if you add a accept: application/json header if you can get it in Json format directly

Comment: To anyone who clicked "Close": the selected dupe covers the XML parsing, but NOT the conversion from XML(-object/node) to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string xml = "YOUR INPUT";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Comment: thanks for answering,   `YOUR INPUT` in my case is `string xml= "<!-- this is the info of the user --> \r\n<User>\r\n<Name>Jhon Doe</Name>\r\n<Identification>10538181</Identification>\r\n<Email>JhonDoe@gmail.com</Email></User> "` ?

Comment: yes,that's it...